# Performance Monitoring tool for plain Ruby/JRuby application

Tags: ruby, newrelic

We aren't using Rails and its not a Web application either we use JRuby and Ruby application and that pick message over a queue operate on them and

We are wondering is there a way to check the performance such application like DB timing slow method calls etc without actually starting the Ruby and JRuby in profiling mode.

Currently, we are using diffing the timing for each DB call like this.

```
start_time = Time.now
## Possible DB call.
total_time_taken= (Time.now - start_time) * 1000
```

I don't find this method reliable also we missing metric of method that potentially slow.

So essentially we are looking for something similar to what Newrelic and Skylight.io do for Rails application but for Ruby and JRuby application performance monitoring.

Comment: Use the search term "APM" to find some solutions. Something like [Datadog's APM solution](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/setup/ruby/) supports JRuby and may be want you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scout](https://scoutapm.com/) or New Relic should work if you have a Rack application.  Otherwise you might be able to use [Datadog](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/)

There are other profiling gems which might be of use.

[memory_profiler](https://github.com/SamSaffron/memory_profiler)
[ruby-prof](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof)

There are many others 
https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet
https://github.com/tmm1/stackprof
https://github.com/ankane/pghero

For Jruby you may have limited choices, some of the rack tools or Datadog may work but also see

Jruby see https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Profiling-JRuby